# Wordpress settings page how to add a disabled field using add_settings_field conditionally?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, addeventlistener, wordpress-plugin-creation

I'm creating my settings page for a Wordpress plug-in, here is one of the fields to make a quick example:

```php
add_settings_field(
    'stwc_ft_oosn_0',
    'Enable',
    array( $this, 'stwc_ft_oosn_0_callback' ),
    'settings-admin',
    'stwc_ft_oosn_section'
);
```

Now in this case the field is a checkbox, how do I `disable` this conditionally? For example how do I `disable` it (not uncheck) depending on the value of another setting? Maybe using `javascript`? Is it safe?

I did this test but it is not working, I'm not sure if I'm moving in the right direction:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){          
        document.addEventListener('click', UpdateFields(), false);

        function UpdateFields(){
            if ( !document.getElementById('stwc_ft_oosn_0').checked ) {
               document.getElementById('stwc_ft_oosn_notice_1').setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
            } else {
               document.getElementById('stwc_ft_oosn_notice_1').removeAttribute("disabled");
            }
            //add other checks here
        }
                
    });                         
</script>
```

Comment: `UpdateFields()` as parameter for `addEventListener` is wrong - you'd be _calling_ the function at this point. This needs to be just the function reference, without the braces - `UpdateFields`